# Full-window background on empty webpage?

Tags: html, css, background

Is there any way to apply a full-window background on an empty webpage, without using viewport units ?

The actual page is not empty but all its elements are absolutely positioned and the background stopped working when I tried to proof it against browsers which don't support `vh`/`vw`, and I guess the reason is that there's nothing in the flow so the `body` has no height.  I can fix the height with absolute units (pixels or em), but that won't fit perfectly the window size.

### Update

Some people seem to consider « empty webpage » not specific enough (question on hold), so here is what an empty webpage (ok, with a link to the CSS) looks like :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

As for a basic piece of non-working CSS :

```
body
{
  background-image: url('your image');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set "html" and "body" tags' height to 100% this should work.

Comment: On `html`, actually — and that's what I was missing.

Comment: If applied to the `HTML` tag, it shouldn't be necessary to declare `height: 100%`.

Comment: @KevinBoucher : It is not necessary if you use `background-size: cover`, but it is if you use `background-size: 100% 100%`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a few options. You could place a `position:fixed` `div` at the top of your markup with the background definition:

```
<body>
    <div class="window-background"></div>
    ...


.window-background {
    background-image: url('your image');
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

You could probably just apply the background to the `HTML` tag:

```
html {
    background-image: url('your image');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Setting the background on the `html` tag with `background-size` set to `cover` works indeed.  (I didn't test your first trick since it works with simpler solutions.)